# ItemControl with 2 sources

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-8, windows-store

I have the following Classes:

```
public class agentes
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string idContinente { get; set; }
    public string idCountry { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class country
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string idContinent { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }

}
```

i also have 2 other classes, and have a List of objects of each of those types , country and agents.

my List is filled with the results from a Database query to a sqlite database that looks something like this:

```
public List<agentes> GetAllAgents()
        {
            List<agentes> AllAgents = new List<agentes>();
            using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(app.DBPath))
            {
                var query = db.Table<agentes>().OrderBy(c => c.idCountry);
                foreach (var _Agent in query)
                {
                    var Agente = new agentes()
                    {
                        desc = _Agent.desc,
                        id = _Agent.id,
                        idContinente = _Agent.idContinente,
                        idCountry = _Agent.idCountry,
                        title = _Agent.title,
                    };
                    AllAgents.Add(Agente);
                }
            }
            return AllAgents;
        }
```

Now, what i intend to do , is a list of agents organized by country so it looks something like

[image]

i started with something like this but clearly it inst whats needed

```
<ScrollViewer  Margin="30,30,0,30" Height="444">
                <ItemsControl Name="ListCountries">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" Foreground="Red" />
                                <ItemsControl Name="AgentsByCountry" >
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding desc}" Foreground="Black" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

anyone got any suggestions how i can do this?

Comment: Which bit you're having problem with? Grouping?

Comment: yes , i dont know how to display the agents, in a way they are grouped  with the countries, i can display all agents in a single list, but that's not quite what i want
my final result would be like the image i added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to group by `title` which will create `IGrouping` for each country where `Key` will be your country:

```
ListCountries.ItemsSource = GetAllAgents().GroupBy(a => a.title);
```

and then change binding for inner `TextBlock` and `ItemsControl` like so

```
<ScrollViewer  Margin="30,30,0,30" Height="444">
    <ItemsControl Name="ListCountries">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Foreground="Red"/>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding desc}" Foreground="Black" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: not quite working yet, it just prints the name of the countries. Just a note , the title in country class, and the title on the agents class are diferent things, they are the names of each object, agents object would be called John, and Country object would be called Spain for example. Not sure if that was clear on my inicial post ehhe

Comment: did you add `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` on the inner `ItemsControl`?

Comment: yes: <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" > , like so

Comment: I altered the groupby to GroupBy(a => a.idCountry); it seems to group them now, since idCountry is the thing that relates them, but in the app they titles get displayed as numbers since we are using the idCountry ... hmmm

Comment: you need to join `country` table, select `desc` from `agent` and `title` from country and group by country name and not country id

Comment: could you show me how its done on your answer? im a bit confused , sorry :\

Comment: [`Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534644(v=vs.110).aspx). I have no way to test if this will work but try `db.GetTable<agentes>().Join(ctx.GetTable<country>(), o => o.idCountry, i => i.id, (o, i) => new { o.desc, i.title }).ToArray();`. You'll need to adapt it to your solution as it won't not give you `agents` but anonymous object with agent description and country title

Comment: still working on it ehhe , but as you said, i got a list of anonymous objects with this on each of them{ desc = "text 1 2 3 ", title = "Spain" }